# Merge Multiple Sites/Networks (at least 2) into One Site/Network

Tags: multisite, merging

What methods exist to merge at least two WordPress sites together that already live under one Multi Site instance? E.g. Sites wp_2 and wp_3 become either wp_4 or are merged together under wp_2.

I suspect that this is no different than migrating or converting an existing WordPress site/data into a Network that has been outline [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite) and includes all the caveats of 301 mappings, updating site options, and existing URLS found inside options and content.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to just export the one WordPress site, and then import it into the new site. Don't try to get too complicated with this.

Comment: Have you imported two sites into one before?

Comment: You can run the import multiple times, some manual cleanup afterwards is inevitable and unavoidable regardless of which approach you take